# Unable to get Ruby's #any? to return false with list of nil objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a very strange problem with #any? printing true for an array that only has nil objects.

The background: This is all taking part in the model - I have a list of records in an array and I set the array's element to nil if the indexed item matches certain criteria. Because I was not getting the results I was expecting (writing tests), I whacked in some debugging.

```
logger.debug "SIZE #{my_event_type_time_units.size}"
logger.debug "CLASS #{my_event_type_time_units.class}"
my_event_type_time_units.each { |r| logger.debug "#{r.class}" }
logger.debug "ANY? #{my_event_type_time_units.any?}"
```

Output

```
SIZE 3
CLASS Array
NilClass
NilClass
NilClass
ANY? true
```

As an aside, when I tried the any? with a list of nil objects, it returned false.

```
[nil, nil, nil].any? ## false
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong. This is my first time using #any? but it can't be that hard. Can it?

```
any? will return true if at least one of the collection members is not false or nil
```

Comment: what exactly are you setting to nil? can you pls show us the code?

Comment: How's your object different from `[nil, nil, nil]`? How do you construct it? What happens when you `logger.debug my_event_type_time_units.inspect`?

Comment: Okay, so judging by the two responses, I think what's happening is: because I'm returning a list of AR records, the array is not a simple array (it's an association) and I'm using Rails' #any? method and not Ruby's. The example when I tried [nil,nil,nil].any? was working on the Ruby Array class and using Ruby's #any? method. I'm finding it difficult to Google this but will continue to do so as this needs to be understood. Why have two any? methods is a bit strange and confusing.

Comment: @ants Why? Because it's two different classes. "Why does the implementation diverge in this way" is the appropriate question--the answer to that is because normally when retrieving associations you'd *never* retrieve a `nil`. Rails' `any?` makes perfect sense in context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at Ruby's implementation of `any?`, not Rails. Remember that Rails associations (specifically Arel associations) are NOT actual arrays... they are more sophisticated than that. Anything you return from a model is an association, not an array. Rails monkey-patches things to make them behave like regular Ruby objects (such has `.class` returning `Array`, but that is not always the case. Here's Rail's code for `any?`:

```
# activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb, line 268
def any?
  if block_given?
    load_target.any? { |*block_args| yield(*block_args) }
  else
    !empty?
  end
end
```

And here's Ruby's:

```
static VALUE
enum_any(VALUE obj)
{
    VALUE result = Qfalse;

    rb_block_call(obj, id_each, 0, 0, ENUMFUNC(any), (VALUE)&result);
    return result;
}
```

They behave differently.

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but I suspect that `any?` is not the right method. I would suggest looking into `include?` or even `compact`...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Having two #any? methods is confusing at best. Where do we find out the methods that have been reimplemented in Rails? Googling isn't throwing up much.

Comment: The answer is a bit misleading as it suggests that there are two implementations of the same method. Well, these are not the same method as they belong to different classes and it is perfectly normal to have two classes that implement a method differently. At first reading I even (mis)understood that Rails actually monkey-patched `Array#any?` (or is it `Enumerable#any?`), which would indeed be horrible.

Comment: No, Rails monkey patches it's associations to make the user *think* that it's an array or enumerable... I'm not sure what is misleading about that. It's two different implementations of the same method... One in `Enumerable` and one in `ActiveRecord::CollectionAssociation`

Answer (score 3):

Not sure which version of Rails you're using, but in < 3.1; `any?` is this:

```
  def any?
    if block_given?
      method_missing(:any?) { |*block_args| yield(*block_args) }
    else
      !empty?
    end
  end
```

Remember: Rails associations are not real arrays.

Comment: Why do you talk about Rails version? #any? is Ruby, not Rails (AFAIK). And what does Rails associations have to do with it as I'm just working on an Array with 3 NilClass objects. Or am I missing something.

Comment: @ants Precisely for the reason I said. You said it's a list of records, in a model. To me that implies it's an association. Rails associations are *not* arrays, they are Rails associations, and have a different implementation of `any?`--the one I posted. That's about the only thing that could lead to the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Yes, I see that now but your initial answer was very brief and gave me no info as to the why. Because of the two answers, I can now see what's happening. And it makes sense what you say, that AR will return instances of associations and not nil records. But as I said in the OP,it's actually the first time I have used #any? and wasn't getting the results I expected. I was playing with the "Array" returned (filling it with nil objects) yet the array was still an association and not a normal Array. I've learnt a lot from four chars (any?). Thks for your replies.