# Rails has_many through any? / empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I found an unusual situation on rails 3 app.

Consider the following model:

```
class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :banner_genres, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :banners, :through => :banner_genres
  ...

class BannerGenre < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :banner_id, :banner, :genre_id, :genre, :position

  belongs_to :genre
  belongs_to :banner
  ...

class Banner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :banner_genres, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :genres, :through => :banner_genres
  ...
```

Now if I have a genre with a banner, I get the following lines in rails console:

```
1.9.3p362 :005 > g = Genre.find 62
  Genre Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "genres".* FROM "genres" WHERE "genres"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 62]]
 => #<Genre id: 62, ...

1.9.3p362 :006 > g.banner_genres.any?
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "banner_genres" WHERE "banner_genres"."genre_id" = 62
 => true 

1.9.3p362 :007 > g.banners
  Banner Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "banners".* FROM "banners" INNER JOIN "banner_genres" ON "banners"."id" = "banner_genres"."banner_id" WHERE "banner_genres"."genre_id" = 62 ORDER BY position
 => [#<Banner id: 446, ...

1.9.3p362 :008 > g.banners.any?
 => false
```

Why does the `.any?` returns `false`? I thy with another has_many through association on the same project and it returns `true`.

**Edit:**

I had a typo when passing the code here. It's banner_genres on the has_many. Not genre_banners.

Also the inverse association works as it's supposed to:

```
1.9.3p362 :004 > b = Banner.find 446
  Banner Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "banners".* FROM "banners" WHERE "banners"."id" = $1 ORDER BY position LIMIT 1  [["id", 446]]
 => #<Banner id: 446...

1.9.3p362 :005 > b.genres.any?
 (0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "genres" INNER JOIN "banner_genres" ON "genres"."id" = "banner_genres"."genre_id" WHERE "banner_genres"."banner_id" = 446
 => true
```

**Edit 2**

More strange console output:

```
1.9.3p362 :007 > g.banners.class
 => Array 
1.9.3p362 :008 > g.banners.any?
 => false 
1.9.3p362 :004 > g.banners.any? {|b| b}
 => true 
1.9.3p362 :006 > g.banners.count
 (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "banners" INNER JOIN "banner_genres" ON "banners"."id" = "banner_genres"."banner_id" WHERE "banner_genres"."genre_id" = 62
 => 1 
1.9.3p362 :009 > g.banners.to_a.any?
 => true
```

**Edit 3**

```
g.banner_genres
  BannerGenre Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "banner_genres".* FROM "banner_genres" WHERE "banner_genres"."genre_id" = 62
 => [#<BannerGenre id: 4, genre_id: 62, banner_id: 446, position: 1, created_at: "2013-03-15 16:41:10", updated_at: "2013-03-15 16:41:10">]
```

**Edit 4** Asked by Aleks

*could you please show queries that are shown on g.banners.any? and g.banners.* 
 It's exactly the same query, which it's even stranger. I also didn't override the any? method anywhere.

```
1.9.3p362 :037 > g.banners(true)
  Banner Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "banners".* FROM "banners" INNER JOIN "banner_genres" ON "banners"."id" = "banner_genres"."banner_id" WHERE "banner_genres"."genre_id" = 62 ORDER BY position
 => [#<Banner id: 446, ...
1.9.3p362 :038 > g.banners(true).any?
  Banner Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "banners".* FROM "banners" INNER JOIN "banner_genres" ON "banners"."id" = "banner_genres"."banner_id" WHERE "banner_genres"."genre_id" = 62 ORDER BY position
 => false 

1.9.3p362 :039 > g.banners.method(:any?)
 => #<Method: Array(Enumerable)#any?>
```

Comment: Just out of interest, is it supposed to be `has_many :genre_banners, has_many :banners, :through => :banner_genres`? I was expecting the `:has_many` and the `:through` to be the same.

Comment: can you give us all the information about associations on this model?
Either you have to have a `:through => :genre_banners` or you are not providing enough information

Comment: @Zippie, I added the info from the other 2 models

Comment: @omnikron, the association table is banners_genres (BannerGenre model).

Comment: The question is **why?** - why it is returning false, when it is clear that 'b.banners' is returning an array. It is clear it is returning the values. At least from his console. If he posted good data

Comment: @daniel can you please copy paste, at least one part of your select 'g.banners' , just to see whole selection result?

Comment: @Aleks, i did copy paste it. It's the 3rd console line on the original question

Comment: I know, I have seen it. I taught there is not whole selection pasted "[#<Banner id: 446, ..." Anyways. Now having all said, I don't see why it is happening. have you considered something like this? http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/159808339/any-empty

Comment: what `g.banner_genres` return? I would like to know what is in the `banner_id` or `genre_id`....

Comment: @Aleks, I added 2 more console outputs to 'edit 2' based on the link you send me. Also, empty? return true

Comment: What do `g.banners.first` and `g.banners.first.present?` return?

Comment: @Daniel what ruby and ror versions do you use?

Comment: @Aleks ruby 1.9.3p362 / Rails 3.2.11. I'll try with rails 3.2.12 just as a sanity check

Comment: @Daniel no need to check, it is good version. I noticed you wrote `g = Genre.find 62 ; g.banners.any? => false ` but if `b = Banner.find 446 ; b.genres.any? => true` what is the difference between those two?

Comment: @Aleks I want to reach the has_many through property from both models, so both Banner and Genre implement an has_many banner_genres and an has_many genres/banners through banner_genres. It's yeird that one of the #any? methods works as supposted and the other won't work

Comment: @Daniel could you please show queries that are shown on `g.banners.any?` and `g.banners`. You can put in your question to easier take a look

Comment: @daniel where is the `ORDER BY position` coming from? I think it is generating the problem...`position` is an attribute of `BannerGenre`, right? so, you cannot order banners by a column that do not exist in `Banner`. You probably have a default scope or something like it, try to remove it.

Comment: @gabrielhilal, I have a position column in all the 3 models, so that an admin can sort the elements in a backoffice. Even though, I commented the default scope and got the same strange behaviour but now without the ORDER BY position clause.

Comment: @Daniel I might know where the problem is. What are the attr_accessible for `class Banner` ?

Comment: @Aleks :content_type, :content_id, :content_name, :is_active, :is_hot, :banner_localizations_attributes, :image, :wide_image, :position

Comment: @Daniel as everything seems strange here, try to put :banner_id as attribute accessible. and then try to run `g.banners.any?`. Maybe, the values you are allowing to be accessed are null for that very banner that you are fetching. Furthermore, maybe for all banners in g.banners values like :content_type, :content_id are empty. Could you please check if that is the case?

Answer (score 1):

The real question here is not whether the association is good or bad, but why it is showing `false` for array that has elements in it. 
It is clear that it is returning values, but the question is why it is returning `false`

The explanation might lay here: [Unable to get Ruby's #any? to return false with list of nil objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478389/unable-to-get-rubys-any-to-return-false-with-list-of-nil-objects)

See how the `any?` is implemented, and how it relates to your question, it might give you a hint.

See this link as well : http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/any%3F

**EDIT:**

What you are saying:
First you have an array of `objects`. Which will on `any?` return `false`

But if you do `.to_a` you will do something like this:

```
Time.new.to_a   #=> [39, 54, 8, 9, 4, 2013, 3, 99, true, "CET"]
```

And that is why it will return `true`, as you will have object that are not null.

**EDIT 2**

Just to note: `any?` will return `false` if all objects from an array are `nil` or `false`

Comment: before he made the edit the real question was what is with the relationships

Comment: @Aleks, but none of the array items are nil.

Comment: @Aleks, nope. That would give me a NoMethodError: undefined method `baners' for #<Genre:0x007ff933fa70d8>

Comment: @Aleks - `any?` will return `false` only if all elements of an array are `nil` (`[1,2,nil,3].any? => true`). On the other hand, `all?` will return false if one or more elements are `nil` (`[1,2,nil,3].all? => false`).

Comment: @gabrielhilal I know that :) Maybe I haven't wrote that precisely in my "edit" , so I have updated that line, which I wrote. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

`any?` was supposed to return `true`....
I was so curious about this issue that I decided to simulate it.

```
g = Genre.find 1
Genre Load (30.1ms)  SELECT "genres".* FROM "genres" WHERE "genres"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<Genre id: 1, name: "a", created_at: "2013-03-19 11:44:32", updated_at: "2013-03-19 11:44:32"> 

g.banner_genres.any?
(0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "banner_genres" WHERE "banner_genres"."genre_id" = 1
=> true 

g.banners
Banner Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "banners".* FROM "banners" INNER JOIN "banner_genres" ON "banners"."id" = "banner_genres"."banner_id" WHERE "banner_genres"."genre_id" = 1
=> [#<Banner id: 1, name: "1", created_at: "2013-03-19 11:43:00", updated_at: "2013-03-19 11:43:00">, #<Banner id: 2, name: "2", created_at: "2013-03-19 11:43:59", updated_at: "2013-03-19 11:43:59">] 

g.banners.any?
=> true
```

Also,

```
g.banners.class
=> Array 
g.banners.any?
=> true 
g.banners.to_a.any?
=> true
```

There is something else going on in your code...

Comment: @gablielhilal, what version of ruby/rails did you use?

Comment: rails 3.2.12, ruby 1.9.3-p0